# Xcode 6 and MacBookPro 2014 128 Gig with Yosemite - OVERHEATING and Long Load Time

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, xcode

I have a BRAND new Macbook Pro running Yosemite and xCode 6.1. EVERY TIME I try to open xCode it completely overheats my computer and takes 15 minutes to open xCode. I have no idea what is happening. I was going to remove and reinstall xCode but it is now done through the Mac App Store. Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does activity monitor show - as for delete Xcode why not just delete it?

Comment: I am having the same issue. how did you resolve?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Developer account you can download the DMG directly form [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode)